# MDT Not Rebooting for Final Few Steps in Task Sequence

Tags: windows-10, deployment, mdt

I have a task sequence to deploy a sysprep'd Windows 10 image.

The TS works fully automatically after the wizard, EXCEPT for the last reboot.

After 'Restart computer' shown in the screenshot, it does not auto login again.  If I manually login to the Administrator account, it will quickly finish the last couple steps then reboot to a fully deployed state.

[image]

I checked the `unattended.xml` file for the task sequence, and I see the auto login count for Administrator IS set to 999, so it should be working.

Why does it not auto login for the final few steps?

Comment: Checking the logs will give you more information than the unattend.xml content. Have a look in SMSTS.log and maybe BDD.log. Depending on the deployment phase, they are located in different locations but for your case, they should be in %WINDIR%\TEMP\DeploymentLogs

Comment: @ZivkoKozarov nothing shows up in the logs that seems out of the ordinary/related to this.

Comment: Is the computer already joined to the domain when the autologon stops working? (when you have to logon manually for the task sequence to continue)

Comment: @ZivkoK no.  It runs that after it logs in (it immdiately does EnableLoginAnimation and the rest of the TS)

Comment: I was suspecting a problem with GPOs applied to the computer before the end of the task sequence, that's the most common issue with autologon not working till the end. By default, the computer is joined to the domain during Windows Setup but If you did perform the necessary modifications to your unattend.xml (remove the joindom node) to ensure that it is only done during "Recover from Domain" step, then it must be something else...

Comment: @ZivkoK yes, I did remove it from unattend.xml

Comment: @ZivkoK may be related, but also at this final step, it shows 2 Administrator accounts in the user switcher on the lock screen.  It shows Administrator, the account we added in unattend.xml, and another Administrator user.

Comment: Do you have an OU where no GPOs are applied (sort of Deployment/Staging OU or similar)? If yes, try to build it there first, then move it to the final OU. What is this second Administrator Account (Domain, local, exact name)?

Comment: @ZivkoK I tried that (A staging OU with no GPOs applied), but ultimately decided it wasn't doing anything considering I wasn't joining domain until the very end of the TS, which is after this failed reboot.